# Get Current Body via Active Explorer in Currently Sending Email

Tags: vba, outlook

Been trying various approaches from either experimenting or googling but cant seem to figure this one out.

In this code, when the email is being sent from the explorer via a reply, it only grabs the body from below what is "being sent now" instead of a lof it. I assume there is an object I haven't been able to find intuitively that holds this but I cant seem to figure out.

Anyone know what I might be over looking?

Code used

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim prompt As String
    Dim msg As MailItem
    Set msg = GetCurrentItem()
    prompt = msg.Body
    MsgBox prompt
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select 
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Note `msg.Body` is the text body.  Do you want `msg.HtmlBody`?  Please explain 'the body from below what is "being sent now"' more fully.  I do not understand the significance of the images.

Comment: `objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem` is the "Pop Out" of [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/Outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) Change your view so this never appears and you have to use the "Pop Out" by default.

Comment: Unless you specifically want to use ActiveInlineResponse you can use the item passed to Application_ItemSend. `prompt = Item.Body`

Comment: @niton Item.Body was it! Thank you! Post as answer for deserved points